# Popup Alert dialog in react-native Android app while app is not in foreground

Tags: android, react-native, user-interface

I have a react-native app doing a long-running operation (doing BLE transfer of file to another device) that takes roughly 40-50 seconds.
When the operation is complete, I pop an Alert dialog notifying the user that it completed, like this:

```
    Alert.alert('File transfer complete');
```

This all works great when the user waits for the transfer to complete.

But if the user switches applications so the app is not in the foreground when the transfer completes, then switches back to the application, the dialog is not displayed.
I expect the behavior to be that when they switch back the dialog is on the screen, and they have to click 'OK' to dismiss it (which is how it behaves when running on iOS).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AppState event listener to show the dialog only when the app is in the foreground.  There's a good example of it [in the docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. This could be helpful. I guess I could handle the event when the UI comes back to the foreground, and if the transfer has completed, then display the alert. I'll give it a try.